# nth-child - second img of a div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two images inside of a div

```
<div class="my_div">

<img src="1.jpg" />
<img src="2.jpg" />

</div>
```

I have tried following css

```
.my_div img:nth-child(2) { margin-top:130px; }
```

But this doesn't work? Any idea why?

Comment: This should work. Do you have any other elements before the images? In that case, use `nth-of-type()` instead.

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7jvt81fb/. What do you get?

Comment: It applies perfectly with your code..,just check if any other styles are overriding it

Comment: What do you want to obtain? Add suspected result as handmade image, or explain it more exhaustive than by word "doesn't work'.

Comment: Yes, it works now! No idea what went wrong! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `display: inherit;` on `.my_div img:nth-child(2)`

```css
.my_div img:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top:130px;
    display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_div">

<img src="1.jpg" />
<img src="2.jpg" />

</div>
```